# Output to page immediately when call another ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby script , which do lots of tasks.
I can run it under system shell very well . 
During the script Executing , i wrote many code to output current status.

however ,  i run it on a controller on rails.

**CONTROLLER**

```
@cmd = %x[  #{cmd} ]
```

**VIEW**

```
<h2>Command</h2>
<%= @cmd %>
```

now ,  i can not get the output immediately .
it will print all the information after all the task done.

how could i print the output to the view(HTML page) when the script is executing.

Thank you all in advance.